# How do I Cancel a Silverlight RIA InvokeOperation in a Domain Service?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have the following method on the server:

```
[Invoke]
public string GeneratePayroll(string empID,int PeriodID, Guid userID)
{
…
}
```

On the client I call the method as follows:

```
InvokeOperation<String> payrollGenerationOperation;
payrollGenerationOperation = _payrollTransContext.GeneratePayroll(EmployeeID, PeriodID, UserID);
payrollGenerationOperation.Completed += new EventHandler(GeneratePayroll_Completed);

void GeneratePayroll_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
…
if (!payrollGenerationOperation.IsCanceled)
    txtStatus.Content = "Completed!";
else
    txtStatus.Content = "Canceled!";
}
```

On the Cancel Button event:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    payrollGenerationOperation.Cancel();
    btnCancel.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

But the Cancel is not working, I am not sure about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the manual, in this case: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.cancel%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

It looks like the SupportsCancellation method always returns false and you need to override it. But there are other caveats here, as explained on MSDN.

Comment: StackOverflow
expert answers to your questions

Comment: Did you override SupportsCancellation and try to cancel it? You can't expect me to copy and paste MSDN for you. If you don't want to read documentation for a piece of software, written by the creator of the platform you're using- that's another issue all together.